# Finalize method causing a memory leak?

Tags: memory-leaks, javafx-2

I cannot resolve a problem and need your help. When I click on menu I call customer account and then afterwards I close it. Every time I call customer account the memory increases. It should diminish when I close the account, but it does not happen.

**Class Menu**

```
mnItemCL_Cust.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
    try {
      panCenterPrev = (Pane) root.getCenter();
      panCenterAct = Customer.listCustomer();
      root.setCenter(null);
      root.setCenter(panCenterAct);
      Customer.btCanc.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
          try {
            Customer.Fim();
            panCenterAct.getChildren().clear();
            panCenterAct = null;
            root.setCenter(null);
            root.setCenter(panCenterPrev);
          } catch (Throwable ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
        }             
});
```

**Class Customer**

```
public class Customer
{

  public static Pane listCustomer() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
  {
    ...
    final ObservableList<MyCustomer> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    ...
  }

  public static class MyCustomer {
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty idcl;
    private MyCustomer(Integer pIdcl ) {
      this.idcl = new SimpleIntegerProperty(pIdcl);  
    }

    public Integer getIdcl() {
         return idcl.get();
    }

    public void setIdcl(Integer pIdcl) {
        idcl.set(pIdcl);
    }
  }  

  public static void Fim() throws Throwable {
    ...
    rs = null;

    tbViewCL.getItems().clear();
    tbViewCL = null;
    colIDCL.getColumns().clear();
    colIDCL = null;
  }

  ...

  protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    try{
      ...
      rs.close();
      ...// Never happens... why??  
    } catch(Throwable t) {
        throw t;
    } finally {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"End?");
        super.finalize();
    }
  }
```

Regards

Comment: Is this throwing any exceptions, or just not releasing memory?  And then two quick points: 1. Your excerpt from `Menu` is either missing some code in the middle, or braces at the end.  There just aren't enough close braces. 2. `catch (Throwable t) {throw t;}` seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Java usually reclaims the memory you used when it see it fits, so even if you finalize the object, the memory may still be there. However, if `rs.Close()` never executes, probably is because something before it is throwing and exception, i recommend you to check the code before just to be sure that nothing is doing so, also, if you catch an exception is a good practice to log it so you can know what is happening.

Comment: Please, one link or simple example: inside 'menuitem' called one class and whit button 'Cancel' destroy all objects of that class... [i use netbeans + javafx 2]